# PDF not rendering properly in firefox when printing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, firefox

I have been trying to print multi page pdf in an angular project in firefox . The preview before printing in firefox browser is totally okay. The pdf is generated as expected in all browser (google chrome, opera, ms edge etc) except mozilla-firefox. Right margin is not generating properly in firefox(see image below). Screenshot of Two diff outputs for same code are given below: 
`output-in-firefox-browser` 
[image]

`output-in-chrome` 
[image]

html code for the screenshot:

```
<div class="row px-2 margin-4 text-center" style="page-break-before: always;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h5 class="mr-170 font-weight-bolder">PART III</h5>
                            <h5 class="mr-22">Dummy</h5>
                            dummy: &nbsp;
                            <input *ngFor="let x of storeSplittedTin" class="assessment-input-box-len text-center ml-1" type="text" value="{{x}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row border-top mt-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">49</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                &nbsp;<b>dummy</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">50</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 border-right">
                            <div class="row py-2">
                                dummy
                                <input class="ml-4 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" style="width: 30px;" disabled [checked]="parent_legal_of_person_with_disability">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 border-right">
                            <div class="row py-2">
                                dummy
                                <input class="ml-4 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" style="width: 30px;" disabled [checked]="!parent_legal_of_person_with_disability">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">51</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 border-right">
                            <div class="row py-2">
                                dummy
                                <input class="ml-4 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" style="width: 30px;" disabled [checked]="isIT10B_applicable">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 border-right">
                            <div class="row py-2">
                                dummy
                                <input class="ml-4 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" style="width: 30px;" disabled [checked]="!isIT10B_applicable">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">52</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                &nbsp;Schedules annexed
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 border-right">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_51" type="text" value="24A" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="is24A">

                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_51" type="text" value="24B" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="is24B">

                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_51" type="text" value="24C" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="is24C">

                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_51" type="text" value="24D" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="is24D">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">53</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                &nbsp;Statements annexed
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 border-right">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_52" type="text" value="IT-10B2016" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="is_still_want_IT10B">

                                <input class="ml-4 mt-2 input_52" type="text" value="IT-10BB2016" disabled>
                                <input class="mt-2 custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled [checked]="isIT10BB_mandatory">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top border-bottom">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">54</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11 border-right" style="height: 200px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                &nbsp;Other statements, documents, etc.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Verification and signature -->
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"><b>Verification</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-top border-bottom mt-1">
                        <div class="col-sm-1 border-left border-right">55</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11 border-right">
                            <div class="row">
                                &nbsp;<b>Verification</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row text-justify mr-1">
                                dummy
                            </div>
                            <div class="row border-top">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 border-right" style="height: 80px;">
                                    <div class="row">&nbsp; Name <br> &nbsp; Dummy</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 80px;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        dummy
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        dummy
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row border-top">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 border-right" style="height: 80px;">
                                    <div class="row mt-2">
                                        dummy
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mb-2">
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" type="text" value="{{dd1}}" disabled>
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" type="text" value="{{dd2}}" disabled>

                                        <input class="ml-1 assessment-input-box-len text-center" type="text" value="{{mm1}}" disabled>
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" type="text" value="{{mm2}}" disabled>
                                        <input class="ml-1 assessment-input-box-len text-center" value="{{yy1}}" type="text" disabled>
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" value="{{yy2}}" type="text" disabled>
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" value="{{yy3}}" disabled>
                                        <input class="assessment-input-box-len text-center" value="{{yy4}}" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 80px;">
                                    <div class="row">&nbsp; Dummy <br> &nbsp;dummy
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

If I remove the `style="page-break-before: always;"` from the starting then the output looks as below: 
[image]

How can I solve this problem for both the browser?